# apply multiple formula to create a column in dataframe

Tags: r

i tried to create new column in a dataframe using different equations and inputs from other column in the dataframe. the equation i want to apply will also slightly differs conditioned on another column. here is the dummy dataframe

```
   set.seed(123)
   df <- 
    data.frame(
    N = (c(0,0,rep(10,18))),
    I0 = runif(20, 0,10),
    Dt = c(1:20),
    Isolator = rep(1:10,each=2)
  )
```

I want to create new column name **Pcol** using this equation  1-exp(-(x)*((df$I0/df$N)*df$Dt))
and x variables changes based on Isolator. I managed to create column **Pcol** using *ifelese() and mutate()* based on isolators but the input is not taken from the same row. to illustrate

```
df1<-mutate(df, Pcol = ifelse(Isolator %in% 1:4, 1-exp(-(0.5])*((df$I0/df$N)*df$Dt)),
                                  ifelse(Isolator %in% 5:7, 1-exp(-(0.7)*((df$I0/df$N)*df$Dt)),
                                         ifelse(Isolator %in% 8:10, 1-exp(-(0.9)*((df$I0/df$N)*df$Dt)), NA))))
```

I also calculated Pcol seperately by subseting dataframe based on isolators

```
col1<- df %>% filter(Isolator <= 4)
col2<- df %>% filter(Isolator >= 5 & Isolator < 8)
col3<- df %>% filter(Isolator >=9 )
Pcol1<-1-exp(-(0.5)*((col1$I0/col1$N)*col1$Dt))
Pcol2<-1-exp(-(0.7)*(((col2$I0/col2$N)*col2$Dt))
Pcol3<-1-exp(-(0.9)*((col3$I0/col3$N)*col3$Dt))
```

and the Pcol in dataframe differs drom Pcol calculated from subset group. i think ifelse() apply in the dataframe taking in input wrongly when it calculate Pcol but i don't know how to fix it or maybe there is a simpler way to apply equations into dataframe

Please help! thank you

Comment: Can you manually calculate `Pcol` value and show what is the expected output for the given data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply group of functions are normally used for iterative calculations or for manipulating lists, whereas,

Will this do?

```
df %>% mutate(Pcol = case_when(Isolator %in% 1:4 ~ 0.5,
                               Isolator %in% 5:7 ~ 0.7,
                               TRUE ~ 0.9),
              Pcol = 1-exp(-(Pcol)*((I0/N)*Dt)))

    N        I0 Dt Isolator      Pcol
1   0 2.8757752  1        1 1.0000000
2   0 7.8830514  2        1 1.0000000
3  10 4.0897692  3        2 0.4585288
4  10 8.8301740  4        2 0.8289903
5  10 9.4046728  5        3 0.9047422
6  10 0.4555650  6        3 0.1277415
7  10 5.2810549  7        4 0.8425062
8  10 8.9241904  8        4 0.9718350
9  10 5.5143501  9        5 0.9690084
10 10 4.5661474 10        5 0.9590868
11 10 9.5683335 11        6 0.9993686
12 10 4.5333416 12        6 0.9778076
13 10 6.7757064 13        7 0.9979002
14 10 5.7263340 14        7 0.9963455
15 10 1.0292468 15        8 0.7507959
16 10 8.9982497 16        8 0.9999976
17 10 2.4608773 17        9 0.9768357
18 10 0.4205953 18        9 0.4940738
19 10 3.2792072 19       10 0.9963296
20 10 9.5450365 20       10 1.0000000
```

Your manual calculations (using subsets)

```
col1<- df %>% filter(Isolator <= 4)
col2<- df %>% filter(Isolator >= 5 & Isolator < 8)
col3<- df %>% filter(Isolator >=8 )
Pcol1 <- 1-exp(-(0.5)*((col1$I0/col1$N)*col1$Dt))
Pcol2 <- 1-exp(-(0.7)*((col2$I0/col2$N)*col2$Dt))
Pcol3 <- 1-exp(-(0.9)*((col3$I0/col3$N)*col3$Dt))

Pcol2             

Pcol <- c(Pcol1, Pcol2, Pcol3)

df %>% mutate(Pcol = case_when(Isolator %in% 1:4 ~ 0.5,
                               Isolator %in% 5:7 ~ 0.7,
                               TRUE ~ 0.9),
              Pcol = 1-exp(-(Pcol)*((I0/N)*Dt))) -> df1

Pcol - df1$Pcol

 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you @AnilGoyal. Still, suppose i check manually Pcol in isolator 7 in row 13  , the result of is 0.9638506 while result using ifelse() is 0.997. i think the result Pcol when using condition with ifelse() is higher than calculating Pcol from a subset data

Comment: Please re-check, row13 values in case_when is also 0.997, which is same as your manual calculation i.e. `Pcol2[5]`.  Let me demonstrate

Comment: Notice that you have used `Isolator >=9` instead of `Isolator >= 8` in manual claculation of `col3`